# Generating Dictionary<string, Type> from type strings BUT - For UITestControls

Tags: c#, wpf

MSDN documentation shows the following example for doing exactly what i want.
But, but, but... What does one use as delimited item in a string in order to get various UITestControls (for example "WpfWindow", "WpfButton", etc.)

================================== MSDN Code ===================================

```
private static string instanceSpec = "System.EventArgs;System.Random;" +
    "System.Exception;System.Object;System.Version";

public static void Main()
{
    string[] instances = instanceSpec.Split(';');
    Array instlist = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), instances.Length);
    object item;
    for (int i = 0; i < instances.Length; i++)
    {
        // create the object from the specification string
        Console.WriteLine("Creating instance of: {0}", instances[i]);
        item = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(instances[i]));
        instlist.SetValue(item, i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nObjects and their default values:\n");
    foreach (object o in instlist)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type:     {0}\nValue:    {1}\nHashCode: {2}\n",
            o.GetType().FullName, o.ToString(), o.GetHashCode());
    }
```